# SQL linking to "unexisting" data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am faced with a problem

My query shows the total workload per ressource in the coming 12 weeks and it works quite well

```
SELECT  Tasks.ID, 
        Ressources.Username AS AssignedTo, 
        CONCAT(Year(Tasks.DueDate), 
        '-', 
        Week(Tasks.DueDate)) AS Weeks, 
        SUM(Tasks.ExpectedDuration) AS Durations, 
        Assignments.Completed 
FROM Ressources INNER JOIN Assignments 
ON Assignments.RessID = Ressources.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tasks ON Assignments.TaskID = Tasks.ID 
WHERE Assignments.Completed = 0 
    AND Tasks.ExpectedDuration <> 0 
    AND Ressources.ID IN (" . $_SESSION['MyColleagues'] . ") 
    AND Tasks.DueDate between NOW() 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 90 DAY,'%Y-%m-01') 
GROUP BY AssignedTo, Week(Tasks.DueDate) 
ORDER BY Weeks;
```

I need to add a column called, 'Contrary'.

'Contrary', is the availability of all my resources per week, and should approximate to `40 - SUM(Tasks.ExpectedDuration)`

The problem is that whenever a resource is not assigned a task for a specific week, it doesn't show 40, which is the hours of availability.

It doesn't show anything at all for that resource.

I have attempted to resolve this with a LEFT JOIN and it did not help.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT  Tasks.ID, 
        Ressources.Username AS AssignedTo, 
        CONCAT(Year(Tasks.DueDate), 
        '-', 
        Week(Tasks.DueDate)) AS Weeks, 
        **40-SUM(Tasks.ExpectedDuration)** AS Durations, 
        Assignments.Completed 
FROM Ressources **LEFT OUTER JOIN** Assignments 
ON Assignments.RessID = Ressources.ID 
INNER JOIN Tasks on Assignments.TaskID = Tasks.ID 
WHERE Assignments.Completed = 0 
    AND Tasks.ExpectedDuration <> 0 
    AND Ressources.ID IN (" . $_SESSION['MyColleagues'] . ") 
    AND Tasks.DueDate between NOW() 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW() + INTERVAL 90 DAY,'%Y-%m-01') 
GROUP BY AssignedTo, Week(Tasks.DueDate) 
ORDER BY Weeks;
```

Does anyone have an idea about how to solve this?

Many thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: Have you tried coalesce to avoid 40-NULL? `40-COALESCE(SUM(Tasks.ExpectedDuration),0)`

Comment: When `LEFT JOIN`, put the right side table's conditions in the `ON` clause get true left join behavior. When in `WHERE` clause, regular inner join result is returned.

Comment: So nobody gets weekends, public holidays or personal holidays?

Comment: Thank you LukStorms for this useful comment !

Comment: P.Salmon, thank for for worrying : off time will be entered as a Task !

Comment: I don't think it's all that difficult but I am reluctant to publish a solution without testing - it would help if you could publish sample data.